# How to automatically close a new tab/window opening automatically with specific web-address?

Tags: firefox, advertising

Is there a way to automatically close a new tab/window that pops up as advertisement and opening some specific web-page on it ?

Is there any software to do this job ?

Comment: Isn't turning on "Block pop-up windows" good enough?

Comment: @YisroelTech NO!!! they all open, while my popup blocker is on and I checked, there are no exceptions...

Comment: how about an Ad Blocker?

Comment: @YisroelTech Ad blocker is a problem(more like last option) because some websites require ad-blocker to be turned off.

Comment: The problem was actually a virus, so I am closing this for now.

Answer (score 1):

Try one of the more robust popup blockers from the Firefox Add-ons store:

**Popup Blocker (strict)**
https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/popup-blocker/

**Popup Blocker Ultimate** https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/popup-blocker-ultimate/

Comment: Sorry but both of them don't work, I am blacklisting all the websites yet they manage to open just as before I had these plugins.

Comment: @Mukul Kumar, Would you mind sharing some of the webpages that you this issue with?

Comment: This page...every time I refresh it and click anywhere on it, an add pops up. any page on stackexchange domain, youtube and many more.

Comment: @MukulKumar, This page and YouTube do not have popups! If you have popups from there pages you are probably infected by some sort of adware.

Comment: Then, Why are ad-blocks not working, The popup blocker(strict) says that it blocks all popups popping from these commands `window.open`, `a->target=_blank`

Comment: @MukulKumar (you did not say that ad blockers aren't working, you said you wouldn't want to use them...but) Ad Blockers block ads that are loaded from a website, these popups are from some Adware (a category of malware) that infected your PC.

Comment: Any **software** that does exactly that's been asked here?

Comment: @MukulKumar, you need to cleanup your PC from the infection! No software can really "block" an infection from doing what it is there to do.

Comment: Already on downloading malwarebytes...hope it works

Comment: @MukulKumar, great choice, do a scan with Adwcleaner (also owned by Malwarebytes) as well, since it is more targeted for adware https://www.malwarebytes.com/adwcleaner/

Comment: I found 2 trojans `trojan.upbot` and `trojan.MWTGen` and many threats and I cleared them all(restarted my pc) but I still am not getting rid of these on-click popups...T.T

Comment: Also used AdwCleaner?

Comment: Yes, used them both

Comment: @MukulKumar, In all honesty, cleaning infections isn't within the scope of this site you should probably seek guidance from a professional helper. You may try on one of the malware removal forums like [GeeksToGo](http://www.geekstogo.com/forum/topic/2852-malware-and-spyware-cleaning-guide/) or [BleepingComputer](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/34773/preparation-guide-for-use-before-using-malware-removal-tools-and-requesting-help/)

Comment: @MukulKumar [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/q/100360)